# Python - How to send private message form using requests? (vBulletin forum)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, vbulletin

I'm trying to send a PM on a forum that I use, but it's not sending - no error code received.

This is the HTML that I think is causing the issue :

```
<div style="margin-top:6px">
    <input type="hidden" name="s" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="securitytoken" value="1515973553-20dc0500315dc868c0bad3384f0d0adb6b85fdd6">
    <input type="hidden" name="do" value="insertpm">
    <input type="hidden" name="pmid" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="forward" value="">
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="sbutton" id="vB_Editor_001_save" value="Submit Message" accesskey="s" tabindex="1">
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Preview Message" accesskey="r" name="preview" tabindex="1">
</div>
```

In any case, here's the page: http://forum.toribash.com/private.php?do=newpm

But you'd need an account on the forum to access that page, by default.

Here's my payload, using **requests**:

```
msg_data = {
            'title': "Discord registration request",
            'message': "TEST",
            'securitytoken': auth_final,
            'do': "insertpm",

        }



        r = session_requests.post(url, data=msg_data)

        result = session_requests.get(url,headers = dict(referer = url))
        tree_pm_send = html.fromstring(result.content)
```

I'm 100% sure that security token variable I entered is correct, but nothing appears in my sent inbox after that.

Comment: You should use modules like `BeautifulSoup` to extract security tokens from webpages. And you should pass all hidden inputs just in case.

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://www.vbulletin.com/forum/articles/programming-documentation/mobile-api/4023442-api-overview